# Unix command to find the number of debug statements in a source code

Tags: unix

How do i find the count of the number of debug statements that is **without** an `if` checking?

This is an example of a debug statement that has an if checking:

```
if(log.isDebug()){
    log.debug("This is a debug statement");
}
```

This is an example of a standalone debug statement that does not have if checking:

```
    log.debug("This is a debug statement");
```

For example, to find the number of debug statements, i would use this command:

```
grep -ir "debug" * | wc -l
```

Comment: If you're using GNU grep (available natively on most Linux), you could look into `-A` and `-B` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -ir "debug" * | grep -v "if" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple-minded awk program that tries to find debug statements outside your if guards. Adapt it to count as needed.

```
/if.*log.isDebug/ {
    inif=1
}

/}/ {
    inif=0
}
/log.debug/ {
    if (!inif) print
}
```

Comment: How do i put it into a script?

Comment: @ChinBoon, save it as say `debug.awk` and run `awk -f debug.awk` on your files.